# How to achieve factory-reset or bootloader mode for Flywheel (Glorystar Nebula rf3288) tablet without buttons?

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, factory-reset, bootloader, buttons

I've gotten stuck trying to upgrade a Glorystar Nebula 15 kiosk Android tablet (as customized for the orphaned Flywheel spin-bikes) to a vendor-provided **single-file** Android 7.1 firmware image (`7.20191202.115231.img`, 715MB).

A special challenge here: this tablet has **no physical buttons whatsever**: no power, no volume controls, no home. (It simply turns on whenever power is supplied; there's a click power toggle inline on the DC power cord plugging into the back. It's got no battery for unplugged use.)

Following the vendor's instructions (using a Windows `AndroidTool` program `2.35`), it was able to 'Switch' to detecting a LOADER device, and appeared to write firmware - but after a lack of progress ending on a log line mentioning 'Success', I disconnected & power-cycled in an attempt to view my hopefully-fresh-new-stock-Android7.1 tablet - and instead found it in a state where it never proceeds past a 'GS' logo boot screen.

Currently, from this GS screen:

- the tablet only ever appears as "Found One ADB Device" in the Windows `AndroidTool`, whereas previously it could 'Switch' to "LOADER"
- it can be detected via `adb` from MacOS – but oddly, not via `adb` inside the same Windows10 VM for which `AndroidTool` was sorta-working.and, `adb shell` commands give a error about the sh-path not being valid.
- `adb` can reboot it into recovery mode - but without physical buttons, no navigation/selection from the recovery menu is yet possible, and it does not appear to `adb` or `AndroidTool` in this mode
- `adb` can seemingly also reboot it into `bootloader` or `fastboot` mode; in this mode it no longer appears to MacOS `adb`, but does appear in MacOS `fastboot devices` list. However, attempting to connect the tablet while in this mode to Windows `AndroidTool` still only ever shows "Found One ADB Device" (or nothing)

I'm looking for any path out of this dead-end state that allows a re-attempt of the flashing the original vendor single-file firmware IMG, or other potential Android 7.1 firmwares.  For example:

- I've found a header on the motherboard with pins GND / PWR / HOME / ESC / V+ / V- / MENU / K2 / K1. However, hand-shorting PWR or V+ to GND with a small wire (alone or together, at the 'recovery' menu that's supposedly looking for vol-nav inputs or other times), has had no visible effect since the tablet's been in this state.
- Can the vendor's single IMG be broken into the smaller more-specific parts that `fastboot` seems limited to flashing? Can applying those, or some other, smaller steps restore a true "Found One LOADER Device" mode, such that the `AndroidTool` might be able to make another attempt?

Etc – open to whatever gets Android 7.1 on this device, including, at this point, all-or-nothing gambits to resuscitate or brick it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For [your device](https://forum.xda-developers.com/attachments/image_2021-02-08_093943-png.5214595/) you should use a [touch based recovery](https://twrp.me) as you don't have any buttons. If you don't found a pre-compiled recovery for your device, look for [another recovery](https://wiki.orangefox.tech/en/home) or [compile your own](https://www.xda-developers.com/compile-twrp-for-your-device/). You can also try to use [this library](https://twrpbuilder.github.io/downloads/twrp/) to compile the recovery. Once you've got your recovery follow these steps.

> Enable Developer mode in Settings.
>
> Turn on OEM unlocking.
>
> Connect your phone with USB cable.
>
> Allow computer to access ADB.
>
> Now execute the following commands...

**Reboot from ADB to bootloader.**

```
adb reboot bootloader
```

> Should reboot the device to fastboot mode.

**You might need to know your unlock code.**

```
fastboot oem get_unlock_data
```

> You have to send this code to the OEM and they should give you another code.

**After that you can try to [unlock the bootloader](https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/locking_unlocking).**

```
fastboot oem unlock bootloader your_code_from_oem
```

> This step is necessary for Motorola devices, but not sure about others.

**Then you should flash a recovery.**

```
fastboot flash recovery recovery.img
```

> Make sure you're flashing the correct recovery.

**Then reboot into recovery.**

```
fastboot reboot recovery
```

> This should boot up the touch based recovery.

If you're done with all these steps then you've successfully `unlocked your bootloader` and `flashed a custom recovery` on the device. Now you can wipe the device including the OS.

**Note:** when you lock/unlock your bootloader your userdata is automatically wiped. If you don’t want to flash a custom recovery that’s fine, just simply unlock and relock the bootloader.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful! However, I'm currently away from the problem device so can't yet try the steps for a couple days. Also, there's no TWRP clearly fit to my device, nor is it clear that the compile instructions include enough details/resources to build something for this device. (Right off the bat, they mention OS builds – like LineageOS or Omni – that are neither part of the current nor intended state of the tablet.) But, I've discovered its current state is in some sort of OEM lock, so your tips about that step are useful (and may require OEM followup.) …

Comment: As the bounty deadline is coming up, I'll award it, though I'm not sure yes this actually solves my problem. Is it the case that after achieving a touch-based recovery mode, that mode would then be able to apply the single `7.20191202.115231.img` file somehow, in each of its segments – such as from an SD card? Or must it somehow be decomposed and flashed to each of the separate partitions using other `adb`/ `fastboot` commands?

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found that Glory Star has [a support group](https://support.glorystartouch.com/portal/en/community/topic/flywheel-customers) that mentions a solution to this in their community.

There is a video on the link there where it shows a step-by-step procedure on how to update it back to the Android firmware. I tried it and it works. The only thing is it only supports Android 5.1.

I have tried it and it works, but not been able to have Google Play in it.